# why can I not import the Chainmap module in python

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.6 and I have successfully imported from the collections such modules as deque and counter but I cannot import Chainmap.  The exact syntax I'm using is

```
from collections import Chainmap
```

I have also tried

```
from collections import chainmap
```

The exact error message I'm getting is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Chainmap'
```

Answer (score 6):

[Read the documentation carefully.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)  The name of the class is `ChainMap`, with a capital `M` in the middle.  Hence:

```
from collections import ChainMap
```

Comment: thanks, i really appreciate it.